# MapKit delegate ios 7 warning

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I am making an app based on a map with current location. In viewDidLoad I tried [`mapView setDelegate:self];` and `mapView.delegate = self;`. Both work but both introduce a warning `Sending "ViewController *const_strong" to parameter of incompatible type'id<MKMapViewDelegate>'`.

The code doesn't work without this line though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your @interface `<MKMapViewDelegate>` , the file where you set up

```
mapView.delegate = self;
```

For example:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
```

It should remove the warning.

Answer (score 0):

To remove warning, you need to implement protocol `MKMapViewDelegate`.

```
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate>
```

then to know updated current location use this delegate method.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
```